# Dart Packages: Dependency conflicts

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

In a Dart/Flutter project, I have

```
dependencies:
  graphql: '^2.1.1-beta.5'
  flutter_bloc: ^3.0.0
```

as dependencies. However, `graphql` depends on `rxdart: ^0.22.0` and `flutter_bloc` depends on `rxdart: ^0.23.0`, which give me error:

```
Because flutter_bloc >=3.0.0 depends on bloc ^3.0.0 which depends on rxdart ^0.23.0, flutter_bloc >=3.0.0 requires rxdart ^0.23.0.
And because graphql 2.1.1-beta.5 depends on rxdart ^0.22.0 and no versions of graphql match >2.1.1-beta.5 <3.0.0, flutter_bloc >=3.0.0 is incompatible with graphql ^2.1.1-beta.5.
So, because com.myapp depends on both graphql ^2.1.1-beta.5 and flutter_bloc ^3.0.0, version solving failed.
```

My temporary fix is to downgrade `flutter_bloc` to `^2.1.1`, which uses `rxdart ^0.23.0`. But if I want to use the latest and greatest version of `flutter_bloc`, what is the best solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Check it out: [Flutter 2 upgrade - Flutter version solving failed error](https://medium.com/@pratikbutani/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 26):

You can use [dependency overrides](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependency_overrides:
  rx_dart: ^0.23.0
```

Note that plugins that depend on another version of the dependency you override can break if you do this.

Comment: Is there a way to use different versions of a common package for different dependencies?

Comment: flutter_bloc: ^3.0.0 does not have any major changes. It has just changed the "builder" property of BlocProvider to "create". That's it ! my suggestion would be to stick on the old version of flutter_bloc

Answer (score 16):

**Disclaimer:** I am not the owner of the answer. I am just posting answer from reference: https://iiro.dev/resolving-dart-package-version-conflicts/

This helped me.

Let's say you have problem like this:

```
Because intl_translation 0.17.0 depends on petitparser ^1.1.3 and xml >=3.2.0 
depends on petitparser ^2.0.0, intl_translation 0.17.0 is incompatible with xml >=3.2.0.

So, because my_project depends on both xml ^3.2.0 and intl_translation 0.17.0, 
version solving failed.
```

The pubspec file might look a little something like this:

```
pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  # ...
  xml: ^3.2.0
  intl_translation: ^0.17.0
```

**Solution**:
The fastest way to resolve this problem is to set the versions of both of the conflicting dependencies to `any`.

```
pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  # ...
 xml: any # <- don't leave me like this - read further!

 intl_translation: any # <- don't leave me like this either!
```

**^^This is not solution, there is one more step!**

The output might like below:

```
Resolving dependencies... 
Got dependencies!
```

After getting the project to build, **you should tighten the dependency versions** back to use semantic versioning like they previously did.
Open the **generated** `pubspec.lock` **file** and **find the dependencies that were previously conflicting**.

```
pubspec.lock
# Generated by pub
# See https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/glossary#lockfile
packages:
  xml:
    # ...
    version: "3.0.1" # the version of "xml" package that worked fine
                     # with "intl_translation".
  intl_translation:
    # ...
    version: "0.17.0" # the version of "intl_translation" package
                      # that worked fine with "xml".
```

From that lockfile, we can see that the xml package version *3.0.1* and intl_translation package version *0.17.0* play along together well.
As the last step, replace any with the correct versions on your pubspec file:

```
pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  # ...
  xml: ^3.0.1
  intl_translation: ^0.17.0
```

Refetch your dependencies one last time by running `flutter packages get` to verify that this does indeed work and then **you’re good to go**.

Answer credits: ***Iiro Krankka***

Comment: Great answer! Didn't know that strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command: `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`