# Flutter: flutter pub get and flutter packages get failed

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, python-requests

I upgraded my flutter version to the latest one and I'm updating my dependencies in my pubspec.yaml.

Whenever I run flutter packages get or flutter pub get I get this error:

[image: Error showing in terminal]

This is what my dependencies look like:

[image: Dependencies in pubspec.yaml]

Could someone please help me fix this bug?

Comment: downgrade http to ^0.12.0

Comment: Coz most of the dependencies depends on other libraries when one is upgraded then depending should too

Comment: @MajidAli I did downgrade and it tells be that there's an error for the firebase_storage_web because it depends on http 0.13.0

Comment: yeah bro thats the problem..check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [dependency overrides](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) in pubspec.yaml:

```
dependency_overrides:
   firebase_auth_web: ^1.0.3
```

but plugins that depend on another version of the dependency you override can break if you do this.

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59548919/7924565)

Answer (score 0):

```
   firebase_auth:
```

Just use the dependency name no need to declare the version in pubspec.yml file